# Android layer images

Tags: android

I draw a set of images on-top of each other similar to http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisserver/9.3/java/geodatabases/data_themes_as_layers.gif where each image have transparent areas and a area that is clickable. The idea is to have a image of a vehicle with clickable areas, off course some areas aren't clickable which are transparent.

Each image is a different formats: HDPI, MDPI, XHDPI, XXHDPI, XXXHDPI.
When render it cause a crash on some device since it run out of memory so obviously am doing something wrong here or the images are too big? I did check the size of the images and they all according to specification.

Layout that i use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ScreenLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/BASE"
        android:tag="-1"
        android:src="@drawable/car_base_right"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/car_B1"
        android:tag="0"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/car_B1_green"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/car_B2"
        android:tag="0"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/car_B2_green"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/car_B3"
        android:tag="0"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/car_B3_green"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/car_B4"
        android:tag="0"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/car_B4_green"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/car_B5"
        android:tag="0"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/car_B5_green"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/car_B6"
        android:tag="0"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/car_B6_green"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/car_B7"
        android:tag="0"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/car_B7_green"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/car_B8"
        android:tag="0"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/car_B8_green"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/car_B9"
        android:tag="0"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/car_B9_green"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/car_B10"
        android:tag="0"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/car_B10_green"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/car_B11"
        android:tag="0"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/car_B11_green"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: `out of memory` Reduce image size & resolutions

Comment: image size is according to specification per MDPI, HDPI etc. Resolution is per the DPI as in per the specification. Please advise how to reduce it ?

Comment: You better use VectorDrawables (which is an SVG **subset**).

Comment: @FrankN.Stein Sir , Its a good approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You are dealing with large images and loading all of them at run time.
>   You have to deal very carefully with large images by loading the size
>   that you need not the whole images at once and then do scaling.

### Solutions

1. Reduce image size & resolutions .
2. **`android:largeHeap=”true”`** flags in manifest file.